# Pointers and Memory Allocation in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

Program:

```
int x;
int *y;
int **z;

z = (int **) malloc (sizeof(int *));
y = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int));
x = 1;
*z = &x;
*y = x;
.
.
.
```

Question:
What is the difference between:

```
*z = &x;
*y = x;
```

From what I understand *z points to the address of x and *y points to x, but for *y to point to x doesn't that require the address of x? I don't really understand what's going on with these two variables.

Edit:
I also want to know when do we know when a variable is allocated on the stack or on the heap?

- Why is x,y, and z allocated on the stack?
- Why is *y, **y, *z, **z, allocated on the heap?

Finally, does changing *z, change **z?

Comment: "From what I understand ..." You misunderstand. z and y still point to whatever memory block they pointed to when you allocated them.

Comment: You shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C. This will help identify the bug of not having a prototype for it.

Comment: First and foremost you need to understand that those last two statements are entirely different.  The first assigns the *address* of x to whatever z points to, while the second assigns the *value* of of x to whatever y points to.  If you assign a value then the original and the copy become "disconnected" so that changing one will not change the other.  But when you use just the address then the two are joined at the hip -- change one and you change the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`z` is a pointer to a pointer (which will typically point to a dynamically allocated array of pointers).

`y` is a pointer to `int`. Again, more often than not it'll point to a dynamically allocated array of `int`s.

So, the `*z = &x;` is setting the pointer that `z` refers to to point at `x`. I.e., `z` points at a pointer, which (in turn) points to `x`.

`*y = x;` is taking the *value* of `x` and assigning it to the `int` pointed to by `y`.

For things like this, a picture is often helpful. So, our basic definitions give us this:

[image]

The we do:

```
z = (int **) malloc (sizeof(int *));
y = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int));
```

Which gives us this:

[image]

Then we do:

```
*z = &x;
*y = x;
```

Which gives us this:

[image]

In all of these, a dashed line signifies a pointer from one place to another, while the solid line indicates copying a value from one place to another.

We can then consider the long-term differences between them. For example, consider what happens if we add `x=2;` after all the assignments above.

In this case, `*y` will still equal `1`, because we copied the value `1` from `x` to `*y`. `**z` will equal `2` though, because it's just a pointer to `x` -- any change in `x` will be reflected in `**z`.

Answer (score 2):

This line stores the *address* of variable `x` in the memory pointed to by `z`:

```
*z = &x;
```

This line stores the *value* of `x` into memory pointed to by `y`:

```
*y = x;
```

The two assignment statements are unrelated: the second one makes a copy, while the first one does not. If you change the value of `x` and then retrieve `**z`, you will see the new value of `x`; however, retrieving `*y` would give you back the old value of `x` (i.e. `1`).

Comment: Thank you! This makes so much sense!